# Return from a promise

Tags: node.js, promise, telegram, imdb, telegraf

I'm currently programming a bot for Telegram with [Telegraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegraf), the Node API, trying to get the returned value from a promise in the [IMDB API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imdb-api), and work's fine for some cases. The problem is that the catch always run and, for some cases, the IMDB API doesn't find the movie when the in the inline search but find it when using the /search.

```
const Telegraf = require( 'telegraf' )
const imdb = require( 'imdb-api' )
const bot = new Telegraf( process.env.BOT_TOKEN )

bot.command( 'search', ctx => {
    const movie = ctx.message.text.split(' ').slice( 1 ).join(' ')

    imdb.get( movie ).then( response => ctx.reply( response.imdburl ) )
    .catch( console.log( 'Reject promise in search function' ) )
} )

function inline_search( movie, callback ) {
    const inline = [ ]

    imdb.get( movie )
    .then( response => {
            inline.push( {
                id: response.title,
                title: response.title,
                type: 'article',
                input_message_content: {
                    message_text: response.imdburl,
                    parse_mode: 'HTML'
                },
                url: response.url,
                description: response.plot,
                thumb_url: response.poster
                }
            )
        callback( inline )
    } )
    .catch( console.log( 'Reject promise in inline search function' ) )
}

bot.on( 'inline_query', ctx => {
    const movie = ctx.inlineQuery.query || ''

    inline_search( movie, response => {
        const result = response
                        .filter( value => value.title.toLowerCase()
                        .indexOf( movie.toLowerCase() ) !== -1 )

        ctx.answerInlineQuery( result )
    } )
} )
```

Comment: That global `inline` array sounds like a horrible idea

Comment: @Bergi, I followed this [example](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/develop/examples/inline-bot.js)

Comment: They use `countries` as a global because it's a constant. You are modifying `inline` on every query, and even if you intended to only use it as a cache, beware of privacy issues.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, l will make it local.